# Downloadable Clojure reference manual

Tags: clojure, documentation

I can't find a downloadable version of Clojure reference manual (preferably PDF). Does any body know of a place from where I can download one?

Answer (score 27):

## Updated 2019

You can download DevDocs offline here [Chrome extension link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devdocs/mnfehgbmkapmjnhcnbodoamcioleeooe?hl=en) and download the Clojure documentation for offline use.

## Updated 2017

Reference Page for Clojure is here: https://clojure.org/reference

## Rich Hickey

1. **One and only Clojure cheat sheet** [html](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) [pdf](https://github.com/jafingerhut/clojure-cheatsheets/blob/master/pdf/cheatsheet-usletter-color.pdf?raw=true)
2. [Approach to concurrency](http://jaoo.dk/dl/jaoo-aarhus-2009/slides/RichHickey_TheClojureConcurrencyStory.pdf)

### Others

1. [Clojure in Small Pieces](http://jaoo.dk/dl/jaoo-aarhus-2009/slides/RichHickey_TheClojureConcurrencyStory.pdf)
2. [Finding Clojure](https://s3.amazonaws.com/kurtharriger-public/FindingClojure.pdf)
3. [Fleet And Enlive Comparison](http://clojure.org/file/view/clojure-cheat-sheet-a4.pdf/186272905/clojure-cheat-sheet-a4.pdf)
4. **Stuart Halloway's great presentations** [Main Download Page](https://github.com/stuarthalloway/clojure-presentations/downloads) / [Clojure Training](https://github.com/downloads/stuarthalloway/clojure-presentations/ClojureTrainingForThoughtworks.pdf)
5. Functional Web - [Google App Engine And Clojure](http://steve.vinoski.net/pdf/IC-Getting_Started_with_Google_App_Engine_and_Clojure.pdf)
6. [Programming Clojure - Free Chapter](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/flow.pdf)
7. [Incanter Cheat Sheet](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/richhickey/clojure/clojure-cheat-sheet-a4-grey.pdf)

Comment: So the correct asnwere here is: There is no reference manual?!

This is a pretty sad state for any programming language. You need an authorative source of truth. A cheat sheet or a tutorial are no replacement for this.

Comment: @HeinrichHartmann added the reference page.

Comment: Great! Now the last missing bit is a printable version that fit's under a pillow : )

Answer (score 9):

Before my last flight i went to [the API](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/) page and saved a copy to my laptop. This was a handy reference for core though worked less well for contrib.

When on the road I use the `doc` and `find-doc` functions a lot.

Comment: Same content, but on github: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/gh-pages

Comment: I agree, now that this exists we should use it instead of my old link.

Answer (score 6):

The official [clojure](http://clojure.org) website offers a handy [cheat sheet](http://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) which is also [downloadable as PDF](https://github.com/jafingerhut/clojure-cheatsheets/blob/master/pdf/cheatsheet-usletter-color.pdf?raw=true)

Comment: Dead link. Do you know where it went?

Comment: updated to use the now actual links

Answer (score 0):

`wget -r http://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet` downloads the cheatsheet and all the pages it links to.